# ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE using Angular 7 and ASP.Net Core 2.2 in Google Chrome browser

Tags: angular, google-chrome, asp.net-core, angular7

I have an application which is using Angular 7 for the front end and ASP.Net Core 2.2 for serving APIs. When I am sending `POST` or `PUT` requests using Google Chrome browser, I get `ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE` error.

When I downgrade my .Net Core to version 2.1, everything works fine

Also when I am testing my app in Firefox, again everything is working fine!

I do not know how to resolve this issue

I am using Google Chrome version 71

When I check the Network tab in Google Chrome, I found that Chrome sends a preflight request to the server too...

Here is what recorded in Network tab:

First:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:12346/api/XXXX
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 204 No Content
Remote Address: [::1]:12346
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

Then:(which cause the error)

```
Request URL: http://localhost:12346/api/XXXX
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
```

As you see chrome does not send any `POST` request to the server (which should send).

Comment: Did you find a solution @Vahid ?

Comment: @AnthonyLiriano Not yet. This problem made me to downgrade to .Net Core 2.1 temporarily.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This may have to do with ASP NET Core 2.2 as you figured. There's an issue registered on GitHub **https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/4398**

And the work-around is as follows - add the following bit of code in your `startup.cs` class (I've kept this first in `Configure` method)

```
app.Use(async (ctx, next) =>
{
  await next();
  if (ctx.Response.StatusCode == 204)
  {
    ctx.Response.ContentLength = 0;
  }
});
```

Do keep track of the GitHub issue.

Comment: As of last nigth, fix has been merged into SDK of ASP.NET Core 2.2.1. If you download and install it, workaround is not needed anymore.